# Display an image instead of the selected text in a <select> input?

Tags: android, html, css

Is it possible to display an image instead of the selected text for a `<select>` input using CSS?

Specifically, I'd like to do this for mobile devices since I have a select input that's a bit too wide to fit nicely in the layout (it just has enough room for a couple of letters anyway). So I'd like to just display an image instead of the text when the select box is unselected, but still use the normal list of text items when the user taps it.

Due to request, here's my HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think styling selects is very limited in what can be done based on what browser you are using - I've always had to use a js plugin that will make an unordered list from the dropdown and apply my styling to that

Comment: @LGSon Sure thing, I added the markup to the question. Let me know if that helps any... :)

Comment: I think it's better to use jquery plugins like `Chosen` https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry, I didn't read your question fully (was reviewing questions and kind of simply made a comment to have it more complete), but this can't be done with CSS alone. Posted an answer with the absolute minimal script how this could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a wrapper and a pseudo. It is an *almost CSS only* solution, it needs a small script to work, and because it becomes the smallest being inline, I added it as such.

Wrap all the below in a media query to control at which sizes it should kick in.

```css
[data-select] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
[data-select]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
[data-select].idx::before {           /* add arrow when an option is selected */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 11px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1
}
[data-select] select {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
[data-select].idx select {            /* hide text when an option is selected */
  font-size: 0;
}
[data-select].idx option {            /* reset text when an option is selected */
  font-size: 16px;
}
[data-select] option:first-child {
  display: none;                      /* remove first option from list */
}
[data-select].idx.nr1::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/bbb);
}
[data-select].idx.nr2::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/f99);
}
[data-select].idx.nr3::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/9f9);
}
[data-select].idx.nr4::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/6bf);
}
```

```html
<div data-select>
  <select onchange="this.parentElement.className = 'idx nr' + this.selectedIndex;">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

And here is a more recommended way, using `addEventListener`

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  /* if only one select, use querySelector() */
  
  document.querySelector('div[data-select]').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    this.className = e.target.dataset.class + e.target.selectedIndex;
  })  

  /* if more than one select, use querySelectorAll() */
  /*
  var ds = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-select]');
  for (var i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
    ds[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){
      this.className = e.target.dataset.class + e.target.selectedIndex;
    })
  }
  */
})
```

```css
[data-select] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
[data-select]::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
[data-select].idx::before {           /* add arrow when an option is selected */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 11px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1
}
[data-select] select {
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
[data-select].idx select {            /* hide text when an option is selected */
  font-size: 0;
}
[data-select].idx option {            /* reset text when an option is selected */
  font-size: 16px;
}
[data-select] option:first-child {
  display: none;                      /* remove first option from list */
}
[data-select].idx.nr1::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/bbb);
}
[data-select].idx.nr2::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/f99);
}
[data-select].idx.nr3::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/9f9);
}
[data-select].idx.nr4::after {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x50/6bf);
}
```

```html
<div data-select>
  <select data-class='idx nr'>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by toggling classes for displaying corresponding images written in media query for mobile devices on the required Select.

```
<select id="demo">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

And the CSS

```
@media and screen (max-width: 767px) {
  #demo { 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   height: 30px;
   width: 50px;
   font-size: 0;
  }
  #demo option {
    font-size: initial;
  }
  .opt1 {
   background-image: url("opt1.png");
  }
  .opt2 {
   background-image: url("opt3.png");
  }
  .opt3 {
   background-image: url("opt3.png");
  }
}
```

And script to toggle the classes on Select change.

```
$("#demo").change(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
      val = $this.val();
  $this.removeClass('opt1 opt2 opt3').addClass('opt'+val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try this:**

**css**

```
select {
  width:500px;
  height:34px;
  padding:10px;
}
select.new {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    padding-right: 24px;
    background: url(http://i64.tinypic.com/2eyjjmh.png) 97.5% 0px no-repeat #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <select class="new">
     <option>ONE</option>
     <option>TWO</option>
  </select>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wg397ccm/)